# How to define the starting position of every bar in chartjs bar

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, linechart, react-chartjs

I am trying to build a graph similar to the one in the image [image: mix of bar chart with line chart]

but I can't find the right way to do it, I want to join the line with the bar on the same axis, and for every bar I want to define the starting Y position and the ending Y position, I tried to do it using multi axis but it didn't work, what I tried is something similar to this

```
    const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', July'],
     datasets: [{
      label: 'Sales',
      type:'line',
      data: [51, 65, 40, 49, 60, 37, 40],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: '#EC932F',
      backgroundColor: '#EC932F',
      pointBorderColor: '#EC932F',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#EC932F',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#EC932F',
      pointHoverBorderColor: '#EC932F',
      yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'
    },{
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Visitor',
      data: [200, 185, 590, 621, 250, 400, 95],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: '#71B37C',
      borderColor: '#71B37C',
      hoverBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
      hoverBorderColor: '#71B37C',
      yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
    }]
};

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'label'
  },
  elements: {
    line: {
      fill: false
    }
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        labels: {
          show: true
        }
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'left',
        id: 'y-axis-1',
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        labels: {
          show: true
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'right',
        id: 'y-axis-2',
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        labels: {
          show: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

but this way, there will be two axes, one on the left and the other on the right side, but both start from the same position